# SQL Server : check user/password is valid without trying connect

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, methods, sql-server-2016

We have built a vb.net (2015) application that requires the user to logon using name and password. The app only requires a valid login since the active connection does the work using a hidden connection with very specific rights, however we must validate the real user

As far as I am aware, the only way to check a DB User & password is valid is to create a SQL connector using the username and password and test whether a connection can be established.

I would prefer not to use this method since the database is cloaked behind a web page API and the direct port to the DB is closed. In the end it is the API that must handle the request returning a YES/NO result to our calling VB application.

Is there as standard stored procedure (or even can we create one) that we can interface to or is there another way altogether?

Comment: Why not have the API validate the user?  It already has a connection to the database - seems pretty straight forward to add a table with user name and password (hashed and salted).  The user enters their credentials, the API checks them and if they're a valid user they can go on about their business.

Comment: Are the user name and password they are providing for a SQL Server login or are they application specific?

Comment: I think you guys have basically answered my question and let the API resolve the user validity.  I am not creating the API so that becomes an issue within our oranisation.  I do really appreciate your responses.